# how to call function in proxy contract

Tags: solidity, dapps

https://github.com/rayonprotocol-research/solidity-upgradable-contracts/blob/master/contracts/Proxy.sol

I'm practicing proxy pattern but i dont know how to call function at logic contract from proxy contract. I think I should use Web3. so proxy pattern is for only web3 or can I call function from ethereum Wallet??
My english is not good sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The client you use doesn't matter when invoking the forwarded functions.

When you have an unnamed function, any calls to the contract that don't match a function selector will be handled by this function. In the link you posted, the unnamed function will proxy the calls to the target contract.

```
    function () public {
        address contractAddr = targetAddress;
        assembly {
            let ptr := mload(0x40)
            calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize)
            let result := delegatecall(gas, contractAddr, ptr, calldatasize, 0, 0)
            let size := returndatasize
            returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)

            switch result
            case 0 { revert(ptr, size) }
            default { return(ptr, size) }
}
```

*(the unnamed function from the code you posted)*

You should take a look at Zeppelin's Transparent Proxy, which resolves an exploit: [link to PR](https://github.com/zeppelinos/zos-lib/pull/36)